# `TypeORM` with `Electron` causes "This option/function is not supported in the browser environment" error when trying to access the database

Tags: typescript, webpack, electron, typeorm, quasar-framework

We have an application that's being implemented with `TypeORM` plus `Quasar`; it is supposed to work in three modes:

1. Backend only: `node`+ `TypeORM`: works okay;
2. Frontend only: `Quasar` + `Webpack`: works okay, communicates perfectly;
3. Desktop mode (frontend + backend): `Quasar` + `Webpack` + `TypeORM` + `Electron` almost everything works perfectly... except `TypeORM` thinks it is working on a browser.

There seem to be two issues on their Git repo that seem close to the problem:

- [Webpack browser entrypoint broke Electron with Webpack](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4210);
- [Unable to load sqlite on electron](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3859).

Neither of them seem to correct the issue.

The problem seems to be that `TypeORM`'s package seems to come with a version of the package compiled for `node`, and another for the browser; in order for Electron to be able to access the databases, it should be using the `node` version; instead, it's using the version that's intended for using in browser.

Does someone have a workaround for this?

### `quasar.conf.js`:

```js
// Configuration for your app
// https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js

const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = function (ctx) {
  return {
    // Quasar looks for *.js files by default
    sourceFiles: {
      router: 'src/router/index.ts',
      store: 'src/store/index.ts'
    },
    // app boot file (/src/boot)
    // --> boot files are part of "main.js"
    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/boot-files
    boot: [
      'i18n'
    ],

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-css
    css: [
      'app.scss'
    ],

    // https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/tree/dev/extras
    extras: [
      // 'ionicons-v4',
      // 'mdi-v4',
      // 'fontawesome-v5',
      // 'eva-icons',
      // 'themify',
      // 'line-awesome',
      // 'roboto-font-latin-ext', // this or either 'roboto-font', NEVER both!

      'roboto-font', // optional, you are not bound to it
      'material-icons' // optional, you are not bound to it
    ],

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-framework
    framework: {
      config: {
        dark: 'auto'
      },
      iconSet: 'material-icons', // Quasar icon set
      lang: 'en-us', // Quasar language pack

      // Possible values for "all":
      // * 'auto' - Auto-import needed Quasar components & directives
      //            (slightly higher compile time; next to minimum bundle size; most convenient)
      // * false  - Manually specify what to import
      //            (fastest compile time; minimum bundle size; most tedious)
      // * true   - Import everything from Quasar
      //            (not treeshaking Quasar; biggest bundle size; convenient)
      all: 'auto',

      components: [],
      directives: [],

      // Quasar plugins
      plugins: [ 'Notify', 'Dialog' ]
    },

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/supporting-ie
    supportIE: false,

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-build
    build: {
      vueRouterMode: 'hash', // available values: 'hash', 'history'

      // showProgress: false,
      // gzip: true,
      // analyze: true,

      // Options below are automatically set depending on the env, set them if you want to override
      // preloadChunks: false,
      // extractCSS: false,

      // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/handling-webpack
      extendWebpack (cfg) {
        cfg.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          options: {
            formatter: require('eslint').CLIEngine.getFormatter('stylish')
          }
        })

      }
    },

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-devServer
    devServer: {
      https: false,
      port: 8080,
      open: true // opens browser window automatically
    },

    // animations: 'all', // --- includes all animations
    // https://quasar.dev/options/animations
    animations: [],

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-ssr/configuring-ssr
    ssr: {
      pwa: false
    },

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-pwa/configuring-pwa
    pwa: {
      workboxPluginMode: 'GenerateSW', // 'GenerateSW' or 'InjectManifest'
      workboxOptions: {}, // only for GenerateSW
      manifest: {
        name: 'Quasar App',
        short_name: 'Quasar App',
        description: 'A Quasar Framework app',
        display: 'standalone',
        orientation: 'portrait',
        background_color: '#ffffff',
        theme_color: '#027be3',
        icons: [
          {
            src: 'statics/icons/icon-128x128.png',
            sizes: '128x128',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: 'statics/icons/icon-192x192.png',
            sizes: '192x192',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: 'statics/icons/icon-256x256.png',
            sizes: '256x256',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: 'statics/icons/icon-384x384.png',
            sizes: '384x384',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: 'statics/icons/icon-512x512.png',
            sizes: '512x512',
            type: 'image/png'
          }
        ]
      }
    },

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-cordova-apps/configuring-cordova
    cordova: {
      // noIosLegacyBuildFlag: true, // uncomment only if you know what you are doing
      id: 'org.cordova.quasar.app'
    },

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-capacitor-apps/configuring-capacitor
    capacitor: {
      hideSplashscreen: true
    },

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-electron-apps/configuring-electron
    electron: {
      bundler: 'packager', // 'packager' or 'builder'

      packager: {
        // https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#options

        // OS X / Mac App Store
        // appBundleId: '',
        // appCategoryType: '',
        // osxSign: '',
        // protocol: 'myapp://path',

        // Windows only
        // win32metadata: { ... }
      },

      builder: {
        // https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration

        appId: 'q-frontend'
      },

      // More info: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-electron-apps/node-integration
      nodeIntegration: true,

      extendWebpack (cfg) {
        // do something with Electron main process Webpack cfg
        // chainWebpack also available besides this extendWebpack
        cfg.target = 'node';
        cfg.externals.push('electron');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### `package.json`:

```js
{
  "name": "q-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A Quasar Framework app",
  "productName": "Quasar App",
  "cordovaId": "org.cordova.quasar.app",
  "capacitorId": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "quasar dev",
    "build": "quasar build",
    "electron:serve": "quasar dev --mode electron",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore ./",
    "test": "echo \"No test specified\" && exit 0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@vue/babel-preset-app": "^4.2.3",
    "ajv-i18n": "^3.5.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mssql": "^6.1.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "node-firebird": "^0.8.9",
    "pg": "^7.18.2",
    "pg-query-stream": "^3.0.3",
    "quasar": "^1.0.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.1.1",
    "typed-rest-client": "^1.7.2",
    "v-money": "^0.8.1",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
    "vue-form-json-schema": "^2.5.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@quasar/app": "^1.0.0",
    "@quasar/quasar-app-extension-typescript": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@types/node": "11.9.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^1.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^1.12.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "electron": "^8.0.1",
    "electron-debug": "^3.0.1",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.4",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 10.10.1",
    "npm": ">= 6.13.4",
    "yarn": ">= 1.21.1"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 1 version, not dead, ie >= 11"
  ],
  "resolutions": {
    "@babel/parser": "7.7.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So far, the only way to make it work was by forking TypeORM's repository, removing the `browser` section from its `package.json`, generating the package with `npm run package` and importing the result into the project.

Also, after that, it was necessary to modify `quasar.conf.js` in order to prevent it from packaging the DB libraries:

```js
// Configuration for your app
// https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js

const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = function (ctx) {
  return {
    // Quasar looks for *.js files by default
    sourceFiles: {
      router: 'src/router/index.ts',
      store: 'src/store/index.ts'
    },
    // app boot file (/src/boot)
    // --> boot files are part of "main.js"
    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/boot-files
    boot: [
      'i18n'
    ],

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-css
    css: [
      'app.scss'
    ],

    // https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/tree/dev/extras
    extras: [
      // 'ionicons-v4',
      // 'mdi-v4',
      // 'fontawesome-v5',
      // 'eva-icons',
      // 'themify',
      // 'line-awesome',
      // 'roboto-font-latin-ext', // this or either 'roboto-font', NEVER both!

      'roboto-font', // optional, you are not bound to it
      'material-icons' // optional, you are not bound to it
    ],

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-framework
    framework: {
      config: {
        dark: 'auto'
      },
      iconSet: 'material-icons', // Quasar icon set
      lang: 'en-us', // Quasar language pack

      // Possible values for "all":
      // * 'auto' - Auto-import needed Quasar components & directives
      //            (slightly higher compile time; next to minimum bundle size; most convenient)
      // * false  - Manually specify what to import
      //            (fastest compile time; minimum bundle size; most tedious)
      // * true   - Import everything from Quasar
      //            (not treeshaking Quasar; biggest bundle size; convenient)
      all: 'auto',

      components: [],
      directives: [],

      // Quasar plugins
      plugins: [ 'Notify', 'Dialog' ]
    },

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/supporting-ie
    supportIE: false,

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-build
    build: {
      vueRouterMode: 'hash', // available values: 'hash', 'history'

      // showProgress: false,
      // gzip: true,
      // analyze: true,

      // Options below are automatically set depending on the env, set them if you want to override
      // preloadChunks: false,
      // extractCSS: false,

      // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/handling-webpack
      extendWebpack (cfg) {
        cfg.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          options: {
            formatter: require('eslint').CLIEngine.getFormatter('stylish')
          }
        })

        cfg.externals = [
          'aws-sdk',
          'dns',
          'pg',
          'pg-native',
          'pg/lib/result',
          'pg/lib/utils'
        ];

      }
    },

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-devServer
    devServer: {
      https: false,
      port: 8080,
      open: true // opens browser window automatically
    },

    // animations: 'all', // --- includes all animations
    // https://quasar.dev/options/animations
    animations: [],

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-ssr/configuring-ssr
    ssr: {
      pwa: false
    },

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-pwa/configuring-pwa
    pwa: {
      workboxPluginMode: 'GenerateSW', // 'GenerateSW' or 'InjectManifest'
      workboxOptions: {}, // only for GenerateSW
      manifest: {
        name: 'Quasar App',
        short_name: 'Quasar App',
        description: 'A Quasar Framework app',
        display: 'standalone',
        orientation: 'portrait',
        background_color: '#ffffff',
        theme_color: '#027be3',
        icons: [
          {
            src: 'statics/icons/icon-128x128.png',
            sizes: '128x128',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: 'statics/icons/icon-192x192.png',
            sizes: '192x192',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: 'statics/icons/icon-256x256.png',
            sizes: '256x256',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: 'statics/icons/icon-384x384.png',
            sizes: '384x384',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: 'statics/icons/icon-512x512.png',
            sizes: '512x512',
            type: 'image/png'
          }
        ]
      }
    },

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-cordova-apps/configuring-cordova
    cordova: {
      // noIosLegacyBuildFlag: true, // uncomment only if you know what you are doing
      id: 'org.cordova.quasar.app'
    },

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-capacitor-apps/configuring-capacitor
    capacitor: {
      hideSplashscreen: true
    },

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-electron-apps/configuring-electron
    electron: {
      bundler: 'packager', // 'packager' or 'builder'

      packager: {
        // https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#options

        // OS X / Mac App Store
        // appBundleId: '',
        // appCategoryType: '',
        // osxSign: '',
        // protocol: 'myapp://path',

        // Windows only
        // win32metadata: { ... }
      },

      builder: {
        // https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration

        appId: 'q-frontend'
      },

      // More info: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-electron-apps/node-integration
      nodeIntegration: true,

      extendWebpack (cfg) {
        // do something with Electron main process Webpack cfg
        // chainWebpack also available besides this extendWebpack
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That's a pretty ugly solution, though.